# Android simple app crashing when I open it

Tags: android

My main class:

```
package com.example.hi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SampleLogin extends Activity {

 EditText txtUserName;
 EditText txtPassword;
 Button btnLogin;
 Button btnCancel;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
           Toast.makeText(SampleLogin.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else{
           Toast.makeText(SampleLogin.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

   }
  });       
    }
}
```

My XML file...

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow> 
 <TextView 
 android:text="@string/User_Name: " 
 android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TextView>

 <EditText 
 android:inputType="textPassword|number"
 android:text="" 
 android:id="@+id/txtUname" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 </EditText>
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
 <TextView 
 android:text="@string/Password: " 
 android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TextView>


 <EditText 
 android:inputType="textPassword|number" 
 android:text="" 
 android:id="@+id/txtPwd" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

</TableRow>


<TableRow>
 <Button
 android:text="@string/Cancel" 
 android:id="@+id/btnCancel" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </Button>


 <Button
 android:text="@string/Login" 
 android:id="@+id/btnLogin" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </Button>


</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

So here is my code for some reason the application stops working when I open it, the "application () has stopped unexpectedly. please try again avd... " I have no idea why that is happening, help please!

I'm new to android, can someone tell me how do I get the catlog file?

About the Strings on the xml file, again I'm new to this, I was getting an error about "hard coded string" or something like that and it said I needed to add it to the strings file found in the res folder so I added the strings and then added the @string

CatLog File:

```
12-28 17:36:50.883: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
12-28 17:37:00.573: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
12-28 17:37:01.933: E/BatteryService(61): usbOnlinePath not found
12-28 17:37:01.933: E/BatteryService(61): batteryVoltagePath not found
12-28 17:37:01.933: E/BatteryService(61): batteryTemperaturePath not found
12-28 17:37:01.953: E/SurfaceFlinger(61): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
12-28 17:37:02.173: E/SensorService(61): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)
12-28 17:37:06.682: E/System(61): Failure starting core service
12-28 17:37:06.682: E/System(61): java.lang.SecurityException
12-28 17:37:06.682: E/System(61):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
12-28 17:37:06.682: E/System(61):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
12-28 17:37:06.682: E/System(61):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
12-28 17:37:06.682: E/System(61):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)
12-28 17:37:06.712: E/EventHub(61): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
12-28 17:37:06.712: E/EventHub(61): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
12-28 17:37:07.122: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-28 17:37:07.122: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-28 17:37:07.122: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-28 17:37:07.122: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-28 17:37:07.122: E/SoundPool(61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-28 17:37:07.164: E/UsbObserver(61): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 17:37:07.164: E/UsbObserver(61):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)
12-28 17:37:07.164: E/UsbObserver(61):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)
12-28 17:37:07.164: E/UsbObserver(61):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)
12-28 17:37:07.673: E/ThrottleService(61): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
12-28 17:37:08.392: E/logwrapper(135): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-28 17:37:08.392: E/logwrapper(136): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-28 17:37:08.432: E/logwrapper(138): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hi/com.example.hi.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hi.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.hi-1.apk]
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hi.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.hi-1.apk]
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
12-28 17:37:35.198: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 11 more
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hi/com.example.hi.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hi.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.hi-1.apk]
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hi.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.hi-1.apk]
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
12-28 17:38:05.517: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  ... 11 more
```

It doesn't crash anymore but I can't type anything!! I changed something on the xml file about typing because it was giving me a problem

```
android:inputType="textPassword|number"
```

I think it was this but when I try to type something it does nothing!

Is this supposed to work?

```
<EditText 
 android:inputType="textPassword|number" 
 android:text="" 
 android:id="@+id/txtPwd" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />


 <EditText 
 android:inputType="textPassword|number"
 android:text="" 
 android:id="@+id/txtUname" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Try putting `System.out.println()`s at each line, and see which line the problem is at.

Comment: When your app crashes, the LogCat (stack trace) will output red. Attach that red part to your question.

Comment: How does this compile? These are compile time errors: `android:text="@string/User_Name: "` and `android:text="@string/Password: "`

Comment: you need use equalsIgnoreCase() method, do not use equals().

Comment: "Can someone tell me how do I get the catlog file?" In Eclipse the LogCat window should open by default. Simply highlight the last set of red lines and press Ctrl+C, then click "[edit]" and paste them into your question. You can also manually open the LogCat window, `Window > Show Views > Other... > Android > LogCat`

Comment: "so I added the strings and then added the @string " The warning you saw means that you should open `res/values/strings.xml` and create a new String element to hold the value, just like `app_name`. Then use `android:text="@string/user_name"` to reference the `strings.xml` string.

Answer (score 2):

From your LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hi.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.hi-1.apk]
```

This means that you probably changed your class name to `SampleLogin` from `MainActivity` but forgot to update your manifest.

Update the manifest to look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SampleLogin"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

(You will also need to address `android:text="@string/User_Name: "` and `android:text="@string/Password: "` as I mentioned in the comments before you can compile your app again.)

Comment: This fixed the problem, the app doesn't crash anymore but I can't type anything on the textboxes!

Comment: Do you mean the EditText boxes? (Sorry, to be picky but EditTexts are editable while TextViews are not.) Please post your current code.

Comment: That is my current code up there, I haven't changed anything in that part but Im pretty sure the problem is here: <EditText 
 android:inputType="textPassword|number" 
 android:text="" 
 android:id="@+id/txtPwd" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

Comment: Are you trying to add letters? You have forbidden anything but numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You should see the LogCat to know what is the error exactly.

The only thing I can spot in your code is that you are initilizing the btnLogin twice and missing the initialization of btnCancel. This would not be the source of the error unless you are using btnCancel object somewhere.

```
 btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
 btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
```

If you can post the error from LogCat, it will be easier to help.

**Edit**

In your layout XML file you have something looks odd

```
android:text="@string/Password: " 

android:id="@+id/TextView01"
```

There are not appropriate name for resources it should be **all small letters** with only underscore as word separator if needed.

Comment: This isn't true. It is true for the layout file names but not for the string or id names.